# Using Soap to download PDF on Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: android, soap, samsung-mobile

So i've created a program that allows the users to buy a bus ticket on their phones, and download a pdf file as soon as the transaction is finished. This is done by checking if the url has changed and contains the keyword: TicsnetReceipt.aspx letting me know that the transaction is done. This works fine as i also save other information like your name/email from the url for future use.

Then i use Soap to download the file:

```
public String getPDFxml(String ReferenceID){
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "GetPDFxml";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetPDFxml";
    String URL = "http://77.40.188.73:28082/SasMobileWS/SasMobile.asmx?op=GetPDFxml";

    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Reference");
        pi.setValue(ReferenceID);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        String strRes = result.toString();
        String temp[];
        temp = strRes.split("TravelDate");
        String Date[] = temp[1].split(">|<|/");
        String theDate = Date[1];
        return(theDate);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


public void getPDFbytes(String TransactionID, String Date){
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String METHOD_NAME = "GetPDFbytes";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetPDFbytes";
    String URL = "http://77.40.188.73:28082/SasMobileWS/SasMobile.asmx?op=GetPDFbytes";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("Reference");
    pi.setValue(TransactionID);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    try {
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = null;
    try{
        resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        try{    
        resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; 
        }catch(Exception f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    byte[] result = null;
    try {
        result = Base64.decode(resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty("GetPDFbytesResult").toString());
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Date = Date.replace(".", "");
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Date + "_" + TransactionID + ".pdf", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        fos.write(result);
        fos.close();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This all works fine on the other models i've tried on, but on S3 it just won't download the file and tells the user the file doesn't exist when he tries to open it in the viewer.

I'm 99% sure it's something wrong with soap that i just can't figure out. But if this looks fine then i have no clue what's going on :p

Thanks in advance :)

After doing a bit more testing i know that the problem comes from:

```
  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

which won't seem the read the data at all, which is weird since it's supposed to be the same input as in the method above.
Both methods accept a string Reference (which is really a number) And the first one, GetPDFxml returns a string and GetPDFbytes returns base64Binary.

just before the program crashes i get the values from envolope and it says:

```
envelope    
SoapSerializationEnvelope  (id=830066090736)    
addAdornments   true    
avoidExceptionForUnknownProperty    false   
bodyIn  SoapFault  (id=830066150416)    
bodyOut SoapObject  (id=830066090472)   
classToQName    Hashtable  (id=830066090944)    
dotNet  true    
enc "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" (id=830065748280)   
encodingStyle   null    
env "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" (id=830065748552)   
headerIn    null    
headerOut   null    
idMap   Hashtable  (id=830066090864)    
implicitTypes   false   
multiRef    Vector  (id=830066102400)   
properties  Hashtable  (id=830066090824)    
qNameToClass    Hashtable  (id=830066090904)    
version 110 
xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (id=830065748824)    
xsi "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" (id=830065749064)
```

And then neither envelope.getResponse();  or resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;  returns a valid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have enough rep, this should be a comment:

If your soap call pops an exception, try adding something like :

```
catch(Exception e){
Log.e(TAG, "Exception during getting pdf " + e.getMessage());}
```

So you can actually see what might be happening.

Now  if your positive that it's the Soap failing, you might want to check your soapservice inside SoapUI ([SoapUI Homepage](http://www.soapui.org/)) which also has a Eclipse plugin : [Eclipse plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html)

And you should try to access your service inside the webbrowser on the device. If it gives a blank page, it's either a device problem or an IIS problem.

On a side note; I personally had problems with my `SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)` number.

---

Things you could add for debugging is:

```
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    Log.d("SoapBody",envelope.bodyOut.toString()); //This

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true; //And this!
```

Comment: in GetPdfBytes envelope.bodyIn gives the message: envelope.bodyin: SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Failed to get the pdf file' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@43ccbed0

There doesn't seem to be any info on getResponse() though. I'll check it out on another phone now and see what message i get from that.

Comment: Also according to a few people getting similar errors it seems the following url's could help: For understanding the soap faults [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/faults.htm) and [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.nl/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html) for using soap with complex objects